# How to set expiration time without adding elements for MemoryCache instance programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, memorycache

I have an instance MemoryCache class.
I need to set expiration time for all objects in cache.
Can anyone help?

```
private static List<UserRole> _userRoles
{
    get
    {
        var lstUserRole = (List<UserRole>)MemoryCache.Default.Get("UserRoles");

        if (lstUserRole == null)
        {
            var _svcFactory = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<QueryFactory>();

            lstUserRole = _svcFactory.GetQuery<UserRole>().
                Include(x => x.Role.Rights).
                Where(x => x.UserId == _userId && !x.DeletedOn.HasValue && !x.Role.DeletedOn.HasValue).ToList();

            foreach(var userRole in lstUserRole)
            {
                userRole.Role.Rights = userRole.Role.Rights.Where(x => !x.DeletedOn.HasValue).ToList();
            }

            MemoryCache.Default.Add("UserRoles", lstUserRole, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(RolesCacheMinutes));
        }

        return lstUserRole;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're setting the expiration time via the third parameter to `MemoryCache.Add`. What's not working?

Comment: UPD > without adding  elements into cache.

Comment: You want to update expiration time for elements?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I need update expiration time without adding elements.
I'm sorry, I mixed up you